# In MFC, How can I have a button to create several dialog instances successively without closing them?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I've already implemented a dialog with a button on it.
When the user clicks the button, a new dialog is shown. But the problem is the user can't click the button unless I close the new dialog.

How can I let the user click the button without closing the new dialog instances?

Here is the code for the button clicking part:

```
void CMyprojDlg::OnClicked()
{
    dialognewone mydia;
    mydia.DoModal();
}
```

Comment: You need a modeless dialog. Search for keywords "modeless dialog mfc" and you'll find tons of examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've found the answer according to your keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a modeless dialog dynamically:

```
void CMyprojDlg::OnClicked()

{
      // Note that: you should free memory by yourself when you close the dialog
      dialognewone *mydia = new dialognewone(); 
      mydia->Create(IDD_DIALOG1);   // create a modeless dialog
      mydia->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);  // show a modeless dialog
}
```

Comment: You still need to handle the destcuction of the `mydia` object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the keyword by Michael Walz' Comment .
I've changed my code into

```
void CMyprojDlg::OnClicked() 
{
    DialogClassName *dia = new DialogClassName;
    dia->Create(IDNumberOfTemplate,this);
    dia->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

And It works.